# How to select one value from an object?

Tags: typescript

I get a data set in one object and I need to display only one value from this object.

If  do this `this.state.number`, then an error occurs:

> The number property does not exist in the type State[]

```
private load() {
  this.statesService.getValueMax().subscribe(data => {
    this.state = data;
    console.log(this.state)
  });
}
```

> console.log(this.state)

```
{
  date: "2019-08-29T07:00:00.000Z", 
  state_id: 21, 
  number: 2, 
  users_id: 207, ...
}
```

Comment: did you do value = JSON.parse(this.state) and try value.number

Comment: please provide output of `console.log(this.state)`

Comment: check your types, apparently you are returning data typed as `State[]` when it in fact `State`. The error message tells us exactly that ;)

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your types, the error tells us exactly what is wrong, you have typed your data returned from the service as `State[]`, where you in fact are recieving a single object according to your console log. So change your service method to return observable of `State`:

```ts
getValueMax(): Observable<State> {
 // if you are also typing data in this function, make sure it's also `State`
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah True output of `console.log(this.state)` says its not array

Answer (score 0):

From error message, it seems state is an array in response.

Try:

```
console.log(this.state[0].number)
```

Comment: is `state` is an array

Comment: So I get this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined`

Comment: is it strigified? Try parse.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a wild guess here and say that the html is rendered before the request is resolved. Try wrapping the interpolation in a ngIf block

```
<div *ngIf="state">
 {{state.number}}°
</div>
```

The console.log updates accordingly the value when recieved, but the html when it tries to render has no value.

Comment: How to put `<div>` inside `load()` method

Comment: You cant, i thought you are trying to output it into html,

Comment: You can put `<html>` inside `JS` unless and until its `React`, unfortunately its `Angular`

Answer (score 0):

your request return a list of objects with parameters (date, state_id, number, users_id).

If you want to get only a result:

```
  this.state = data[0];// this will get first element of the list
```

and in html you can use `{{state.number}}`